# Getting the number of lines in a text file in R

Tags: r

I have text file I am reading into R. eack line of text is the full name of a NCDF4 file. i would like to get a count of the number of files recorded in the test file. Surley there is a little bit of code to do that simpley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you are simply trying to figure out how many lines are in your txt file. Is that correct? If so, something like this will work:

```
dat <- readLines(path/to/txtfile.txt)
length(dat)
```

Comment: Your right. Let me try this and i will revert

Comment: Forgive me When you have (path/to/txtfile.txt) I am interperating that as the full file address ?

Comment: Yeah, just put the file location, in quotes, in between the parentheses. That will create an object, dat, that contains all of the file names.

For example: readLines("~/Desktop/textfile.txt")